# Range of $\cot^{-1}(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

S. L. Loney mentions the range of $\cot^{-1}(x)$ to be $[-\pi/2,0)\cup(0,\pi/2]$ whereas my textbook (my coaching institute package) mentions it to be $(0,\pi)$. May I know which one is the correct convention? I have referred many resources which show the range to be  $(0,\pi)$. Are there any advantages of defining it this way over the previous one?

Comment: Either is acceptable.  Loney may have chosen that range to produce results in the fourth and first quadrants, as arctangent does.  Many sources give $ \ (0 \ , \ \pi) \ $ in order to have a single interval as a "range".  In applications, either convention has to be "manipulated" to obtain angles in the proper quadrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which one is the correct convention?

As already pointed out, as for any other inverse function defined over a restriction, no one is the *correct convention* and either is acceptable.

The two ranges usually adopted for $\cot^{-1}(x)$ are the more *convenient* or more *simple* or more *natural*.

Indeed we could also define the range in infinitely many other ways for $c\in(0,\pi/2]$

$$  [-c,0)\cup(0,\pi-c]$$

and each of them would be a proper choice to define $\cot^{-1}(x)$.

> Are there any advantages of defining it this way over the previous one?

Each choice may have advantages depending on the context, notably:

- By the choice $[-\pi/2,0)\cup(0,\pi/2]$ we have that $\cot^{-1}(x)$ is an odd function discontinuous at $x=0$ since

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \cot^{-1}(x)=-\frac \pi 2 \neq \lim_{x\to 0^+} \cot^{-1}(x)=\frac \pi 2$$

This is for example the function we find on Wolfram

[image]

- By the choice $(0,\pi)$ we have that $\cot^{-1}(x)$ is no more an odd function but it is continuous.

Moreover in this case the following holds $\forall x \in \mathbb R$

$$\cot^{-1}(x)=\frac \pi 2 - \tan^{-1}(x)$$

[image]
([image credits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#/media/File:Arctangent_Arccotangent.svg))

Answer (score -2):

It's better to take the range as $(0,\pi)$ as it gives continuous graph.

Comment: We can choose any of the range right how does a graph being continuous benefit?